# Django app on Apache throws "Address family not supported by protocol"

Tags: python, apache, tcp

I'm currently running a Django app on Apache.
This app is a webservice which occasionally send POST requests (with Python "Requests" lib) to an external server.

I recently changed the Apache server, from the custom install I made in usr/local/apache2 to the already installed version (which uses /etc/httpd, /var/www/...).

Since that, those POST requests always end up throwing a :

```
ConnectionError at /xxx/
('Connection aborted.', error(97, 'Address family not supported by protocol'))
```

If I import the function which send the request in `./manage.py shell` and run it, it works perfectly fine.

I don't think it's Python-related since it was running well before I switched Apache server.

I absolutely don't know where it could come from though, and none of my research have gave me answers. So I wait for yours !

Config :

```
OS : RedHatEL 6.4 x64
Server : Apache 2.2.15
Python : 2.7.8
Django : 1.6.6
```