# Django connection aborted: address family not supported by protocol

Tags: python, django, raspberry-pi

I'm running a script on a raspberry pi that sends a POST request to my Django app once every minute. I ran it for 3 hours at my apartment and it was fine, but then I took it home and ran it for just 37 minutes before getting this error:

```
...
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(97, 'Address family not supported by protocol'))
```

I googled around and found this: [Django app on Apache throws "Address family not supported by protocol"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610692/django-app-on-apache-throws-address-family-not-supported-by-protocol), which is unanswered (I can't comment because I don't have a high enough reputation yet, unfortunately.)

Does anyone know why this might be happening? I've never seen something like this before, and I don't have a lot to go off.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing this kernel module `af_packet`, you can reload it like:

```
root@linux# depmod -a
root@linux# modprobe af_packet
```

if it doesnot work, you can try to load directly:

```
root@linux# insmod /lib/modules/2.6.13-15-default/kernel/net/packet/af_packet.ko
```