# Get an error when installing virtualenv for flask

Tags: python

I am learning to use flask for python web framework, however, when I try to `sudo easy_install virtualenv`, I get an error:

```
[Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol
```

how to solve this? My linux is CentOS release 4.3 (Final) and python version is 2.7.3

Comment: You might want to upgrade to CentOS 7. [CentOS 4 was EOL in 2012](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product).

Comment: Did you tried install with source package ?

Comment: @RajaSimon Okay, I tried, it worked, but here comes another question... when activating flask- "pip install Flask", there is another error: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(97, 'Address family not supported by protocol'))': /simple/flask/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it from source package...

```
$ curl -O https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ tar xvfz virtualenv-X.X.tar.gz
$ cd virtualenv-X.X
$ [sudo] python setup.py install
```

Comment: when activating flask - "pip install Flask", there is another error: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', error(97, 'Address family not supported by protocol'))': /simple/flask/

Comment: can you try this answer.. and let me know http://stackoverflow.com/a/31224813/3762142

Comment: this is not related with virutalenv though.. your server can't connect to internet..! Am I right ?